# click listener is not working

Tags: android

Hi I am new in android learning and I'm practice it. I Want to implement click listener on my button but it is giving me error. even i imported  android.view.View.OnClickListener; and other all libraries.
please have  look at my code check where is my mistake

---

> Cannot Resolve symbol onClickelistner.

---

```
package com.example.nexus.myapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    TextView loginresulttext;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
        loginresulttext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginresult);
    }


    button.OnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button Is Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try **button** click inside **Oncreate()**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    TextView loginresulttext;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
        loginresulttext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginresult);
         button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button Is Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: by doing not error on buttonin line  button.OnClickListener(new OnClickListener(). error is expected class package

Answer (score 0):

Try this and put it in onCreate method

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
      //do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine R2R and Toan Tran answers will give you the best solution:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;
TextView loginresulttext;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
    loginresulttext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginresult);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button Is Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testButton);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
 });
```